# Enviar el valor de un boton a un Modal

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mvc

tengo el siguiente código, estoy haciendo un ABM sencillo, estoy en la parte de Eliminar, quiero que cuando se haga clic en el botón "Eliminar", me aparezca un modal pidiendo la confirmación de la misma. Quiero mandarle el ID del botón al botón "Eliminar" de mi Modal pero tengo muy poco conocimiento en JavaScript para poder hacerlo.

Lo eh intentado con varias funciones, pero ninguna me sirvió.

Mi tabla:

```
   <tbody>
            @foreach (var m in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @m.Nombre
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @m.Apellido
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input onclick="document.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/Edit/?Id=" + m.Id)'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Editar" />
                        <input value="Eliminar" type="button" id="@m.Id" data-id="@m.Id" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEliminar" onclick="Recibir(@m.Id)">                            
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

Modal:

```
 <!--Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEliminar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Eliminar Módulo</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    ¿Está seguro de querer Eliminar a esta persona?
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <input type="submit" id="eliminar" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Cierra Modal-->
```

Funciones que eh utilizado (la ultima fue la funcion (`function recibir()`), la cual le estaba mandando bien el Id a la función, y después asignarle al value del boton Eliminar del Modal, pero no funciona:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#BtnModal').click(function () {

                var id = $(this).data('id');
                console.log(id);
                $('#moduloId').val(id);
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>

        function Recibir(valor) {
            var id = document.getElementById("modulo" + valor).value;
            document.getElementById("eliminar").value = id;
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises la libreria Sweet Alert 2, con ella puedes hacer lo que quieres de manera sencilla: https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Answer (score -2):

Primero que nada te aconsejo que cambies la forma de seleccion, en vez de ser una tabla puede ser un select y alli puedes capturar el valor que esta seleccionado el cual va hacer el ID, y por otro lado agrega el atributo onClick en el submit de ELIMINAR y en dicho atributo llama a la funcion que va hacer el eliminar preguntando que valor esta seleccionado.